Kali linux при установке требует какие то микропрограммы
Проблема что kali требует какие то файлы
ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin
ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin

Там хоть и можно пропустить, но после этого kali при установке Программного Обеспечения выдаёт, а точнее не выдаёт ошибку. Ну ошибку то выдаёт только непонятно какую. У меня Lenovo Ideapad, ставлю kali на раздел диска рядом с виндой. Вроде это от wifi модуля, и у меня без них интернет не рабоает.
